# angular.js:13920 Error: The $firebaseAuth service accepts a Firebase auth instance (or nothing) instead of a Database reference

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

im testing angular fire base and found this example.

https://www.sitepoint.com/real-time-status-update-app-angularjs-firebase/

i created my new database and enabled the email auth method.

later changed the url in authservice.js

```
 'use strict';

  angular
    .module('statusApp')
    .factory('Auth', AuthService);

  function AuthService($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://mydburl.firebaseio.com");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
```

when i try the app i get this error.

```
angular.js:13920 Error: The $firebaseAuth service accepts a Firebase auth instance (or nothing) instead of a Database reference.
    at Object.FirebaseAuth
```

i can't seem to find a similiar anywhere.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using an AngularFire 2.x build. In that case you're mixing Firebase versions. See the code snippets here: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#overview

Comment: now that you mention it, i installed the dependencies via bower and one of the dependencie was a cdn that i copied from the index field.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the bower version is 3.4.4 while the tutorial one is 2.4.4, now im getting ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen does that tutorial work with the new version? seems to me that many things have changed in how you call it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it was indeed the versions that were mixed.

Comment: Good to hear that you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @FrankvanPuffelen the problem was caused by using old dependencies